# connecting to kurento media server java tutorial via websocket

Tags: java, android, kurento

I'm trying to connect to websocket from my Android app but I'm having a hard time establishing the connection. When I'm trying to connect from socket explorers it connect normally, but when I'm trying to establish connection from Android I get this message:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I'm using this URI to establish connection:

> wss://my-ip-address:8443/call

Answer (score 2):

Try to change `wss://`(websocket secured) URI identifier to `ws://`(just websocket). As your local hosting websocket server has no signed SSL certificates to prove it being secure, your Android websocket client refusing to establish connection with it.